# Dereferencing a pointer inside a designated struct initializer in C

Tags: c, struct, initializer

Let's say I have the following struct

```
typedef struct foo {
    int    a;
    char **b;
} foo;
```

And this is what I am trying to do

```
char *bar0 = malloc(sizeof *bar0);
char *bar1 = malloc(sizeof *bar1);

foo f = {
    .a    = 4,
    .b    = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *)),
    .b[0] = bar0, // not allowed!
    .b[1] = bar1, // not allowed!
}
```

GCC errors out as `array index in non-array initializer.` I have also tried `.(*b) = bar0` and `.(*(b+1)) = bar1`, but they aren't syntactically valid too.

**EDIT:**
Is there any way to assign `bar0` and `bar1` within the initializer , and not use separate assignment expressions?

Comment: `foo` has 2 members: `a, b`.   `foo f = {  .a    = 4, .b    = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *)) }` initializes those 2 members: an `int` and a pointer.  `f` is _completely_ initialized.  The allocated memory is not yet assigned.  `.b[0] = bar0` is attempting an assignment that is not part of initializing `f`.  Why do you want to do assignments inside the initializer of `f` that is not initializing one of the 2 members of `f`?

Comment: Can't you just use replace the problematic designated initializations with assignment expressions?

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes that is what I am currently doing. I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it inside the initializer itself. Perhaps I should edit my question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to assign `bar0` and `bar1` within the initializer , and not use separate assignment expressions?

No, `f.b` is a pointer to an allocated object (returned by a call to `malloc` in this case) and an allocated object cannot be initialized using an initializer. Just remove the problematic designated initializers and use assignment expressions instead:

```
char *bar0 = malloc(sizeof *bar0);
char *bar1 = malloc(sizeof *bar1);

foo f = {
    .a    = 4,
    .b    = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *)),
};
f.b[0] = bar0;
f.b[1] = bar1;
```

Answer (score 2):

`b` is a pointer (to a pointer) not an array, so you cannot use array designated initializer syntax. Furthermore, you cannot have run-time allocation with `malloc` an initialization at the same time.

You'll have to do something like:

```
char *bar0 = malloc(something_meaningful);
char *bar1 = malloc(something_meaningful);
foo f = {
    .a    = 4,
    .b    = (char*[]){ bar0, bar1 }
};
```

This assigns `b` to a compound literal with the same scope as `f`. However, you won't be able to re-size `b` itself now. If that's a requirement, then you have to do malloc + run-time assignement in two separate steps.

---

Please note that `char *bar0 = malloc(sizeof *bar0);` is quite senseless if you have to realloc this 1 byte the first thing you do anyway. I'd recommend to either allocate a "reasonably large chunk" or set it to `NULL`.

Comment: Unfortunately I do require `b` to be allocated at runtime. Could you clarify when you say you cannot have `malloc` and initialization at the same time. Is it just bad practice? Because I currently am just doing `.b = malloc(...)` inside the initializer, and then doing `f.b[0] = bar0` outside the initializer, and I am getting the required behaviour.

Comment: P.S. I do agree with the 1 byte allocation being senseless. It was just for the sake of the example.

Comment: @ichigogyuunyuu In my example,  `b` is pointing at a compound literal defined in run-time. You cannot have initialization and malloc in the same expression, because the way malloc is defined, it returns a chunk of uninitialized memory. It doesn't come with a way to set default values other than "all zeroes" (use calloc for that). So it has to be done as a two step process.

Comment: `.b    = (char*[]){ bar0, bar1 }` seems like it could be a bit dangerous, since the compound literal will be a stored as a local variable with automatic storage duration, and the pointer `b` will refer to that object.  It's all to easy for the value of that pointer to be passed outside the block the compound literal is valid in.  Debugging that situation, should it arise, would likely be very difficult.